# Unity - How To Disable Accelerometer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gameobject that uses accelerometer as control input and also touch input. Now the game would be very bad if both controls are active at the same time, so I need to disable and enable controls by a toggle but sadly, the toggle is in settings menu, while the gameobject is in the game/play, so to summarize this:

1 - Disable/Toggle Accelerometer and Touch

2 - Access GameObject from another scene

3 -  How to save the state of the toggle(including the state of the controls)

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your steps are wrong.

Just in setting menu save your variable to PlayerPref:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("ControlMode", 0)); //Accelerometer
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("ControlMode", 1)); //Touch
```

In the other scene you read this value and just set in your control script a condition or similar over "ControlMode":

```
int currentMode = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("ControlMode"); 
if (currentMode == 0)
{
  //Accelerometer input control
}
else
{
  //Touch input control
}
```